# Django - Return a list of primary keys with another attribute of the entity it's referencing

Tags: python, django

I have this FollowUser and User model below and there's a URL that gets a list of people the user is following (followees). I'd like to return a list of the followees (A User model) that has their UUID and the followees username. How can I do this in a fast and efficient way?

models.py

```
class User(AbstractBaseModel):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=255, unique=True, primary_key=True)

class FollowUser(AbstractSimpleModel):
    follower_id = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="follower_following")
    followee_id = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="followee_followed_by")
```

views.py

```
def get_followees(request, follower_email):
    try:
        followees = FollowUser.objects.filter(follower_id=follower_email).values_list('followee_id', flat=True)
        data = dict(followee_ids=list(followees))
        return JsonResponse(data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    except FollowUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response(dict(error=f'follower id: {follower_id} does not exist'), status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: Hello! You do not seem to have a UUID field. You either use the `id` / `pk` or you have to add a `uuid` attribute to the User model if nessecary. I'm not confident about the performance, but I imagine adding a `following = ManyToManyField('self', related_name='followers')` could be a better choice compared to the FollowUser model.

Comment: @SvenTUM sorry I named things incorrectly. The PK is actually the user's email. Yes I was thinking about your suggestion. Perhaps that would be better.